# Infinite loop in Python while loops

Tags: python, variables, loops

I don't know whats wrong. When I put in x*x for the left side, and 25 for the right side, it doesnt work. The python shell shows no errors, but after I enter the amount of solutions, nothing happens. I think that it could be in an endless loop, or not be applying x after each run. PLEASE HELP! Here is my code:

```
#getting input information

print
print "This program cannot solve for irrational or repeating numbers. Please round for them in your equation."
print
print "Make the variable in your equation stand for x"
print
startingLimit=int(raw_input("What is the lowest estimate that your variable could possibly be?"))
print
wholeNumber=raw_input("Do you know if your variable will be a whole number or a fraction? Answer: yes/no")
if (wholeNumber== "yes"):
     print
     fraction= raw_input("Is it a decimal/fraction? Answer:yes/no")
     if (fraction=="yes"):
        print
        print "This program will only calculate up to the fourth place to the right of the decimal"
        xfinder=0.0001
    else:
        xfinder=1
else:
    xfinder=0.0001

x=0        
leftEquation=raw_input("Enter your left side of the equation:")
print
rightEquation=raw_input("Enter the right side of the equation:")
print
amountSolutions=raw_input("How many solutions are there to your equation? (up to 20)")



#solving

indivisualCount=0
count=0
x=startingLimit
while (count!=amountSolutions):


    while (count==0):
        ifstuffleft=eval(leftEquation)
        ifstuffright=eval (rightEquation)
        if (ifstuffleft!=ifstuffright):
            x=x+xfinder
        else:
            a=x
            count=count+1
```

Comment: What is the program supposed to do? Nothing is being printed anywhere after the number of solutions is requested, so there shouldn't be any output.

Comment: This looks like homework. Please tag it as such if it is.

Comment: @serk: The homework tag is now [officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) and should not be added to questions

Comment: It is generally a good idea to use a descriptive title.  Something like `Help!' will gather less attention than `Syntax error in python function to calculate value'

Comment: @David Thanks for letting me know about that. I wasn't aware. Thanks!

Comment: How many solutions did you tell it were possible?

Comment: It seems like most of the "homework" type questions are "too local". I find myself voting to close more often these days.

Answer (score 2):

1. Why do you have the inner `while (count==0):` while loop? That will cause it to get stuck on an infinite loop (in the `while (count!=amountSolutions):` loop) as soon as `count` is not equal to 0 (since it will never enter that inner while loop).
2. Once you've fixed that, notice that you don't perform `x=x+xfinder` if the values are equal to each other. That means you will stay on the same value (in this case `-5`) until you've satisfied the number of solutions. You thus have to increase the value by `xfinder` whether or not the values are equal.
3. You never print the solution or do anything with it. You probably want to replace the `a=x` line with `print "One solution is", x`

Finally, when you're posting a question you should strive for a *minimal* example. All of your input code can be replaced by hardcoding the 5 variables, something like:

```
startingLimit = -10
xfinder = 1
leftEquation = "x*x"
rightEquation = "25"
amountSolutions = 2
```

This a) requires 23 fewer lines of code, making your question easier to read and understand, b) makes it easier to test so people can see the problem without answering six questions and c) prevents answerers from having to guess what you put in for `startingLimit` and `amountSolutions`.

Comment: Yes, but I did tell it to print out the solutions at the bottom when I put this:    if (amountSolutions=="1"):
                    print "Solutions= ",a

Comment: @user1624992: That code is nowhere in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If any value other than `1`  is given for `amountSolutions` it seems like this code will go into an infinite loop.

```
while (count!=amountSolutions):
    while (count==0):
```

In the above once one solution is found, `count = 1` and thus the inner while loop would be skipped.